# Is there a way to change an object in html after 90 seconds of an action with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, timeout

Is there a way to change an object in html after 90 seconds of an action with javascript? I have a download button that, once pressed I want it to be replaced by two other buttons after 90 seconds. Basically giving the download time to process and then giving the user the opportunity to share what they've done on Facebook or Google+. Thanks!

Comment: Google for "settimeout javascript"....!!!

Comment: @recursive because it is a useless general reference question with nothing tried by the OP

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by useless.  The information clearly has value to someone.  I think it's a reasonable question.  It can be difficult for a beginner in a language to know what might be reasonable to try.  In this case, I don't think it's unreasonable.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm a beginner and have been scratching my head at this one before I submitted this question. I'm sure it seems very obvious to you though. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` after said action.

```
function buttonClicked() {    
   setTimeout(dosomething, 90000);
}

function dosomething() {
     // implementation of delayed action here
}
```